# Supporting AirPlay for Photos and Videos in 3rd party iPhone app

Tags: iphone, video, photo, airplay

The default Photos app in iPhone supports AirPlay for both Photos and Videos. But, Apple has given API for setting allowsAirPlay only in MPMoviePlayerController i.e only for videos. If I support it only for Videos user will complain for not supporting it for photos.

How do I support AirPlay for both Photos and Videos in my app? Is there any method/interface/framework available that supports AirPlay and I have to just call it when the user clicks on my custom button?

Comment: You'd probably have to convert it to mp4 first (which can get pretty messy). That's the only way I know. I would personally want to know hat libraries I can use to do that too!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, iPhone SDK 4.3 provides no API for sending photos via AirPlay.